# Trouble with Recursive Database Connection Creation in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, with-statement

I have a question about an error I encountered while working on my first Python project. The error involves creating a connection to a PostgreSQL database in a recursive manner.

My project involves a Python script that connects to a database and retrieves data from it. The problem arises when attempting to establish the database connection. I have a function dedicated to handling the creation of the connection, which I call from another function responsible for retrieving data from the database.

In my main function, I create an object called UserModel and then invoke the update_user_data function. The UserModel has a constructor defined as follows:

```
pythonCopy code
def __init__(self):
    self.connection = DBConnection()
```

When retrieving user data, I utilize a "with" statement to open the database connection and execute the necessary logic. Inside the update_user_data function, I also need to retrieve user role data and add it to the user map. To achieve this, I have a RoleModel with a constructor as shown below:

```
pythonCopy code
def __init__(self):
    self.connection = DBConnection()
```

However, during this process, I encounter an error related to the recursive creation of the database connection.

I would appreciate guidance on how to properly write such functions and follow best practices when working with database connections, particularly when using "with" statements.

If you could provide any sample code snippets or offer further guidance, I would be grateful as I'm eager to learn.

```
pythonCopy code
import os
import psycopg2

class DBConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=os.environ.get('DBNAME'),
            host=os.environ.get('HOST'),
            port=os.environ.get('PORT'),
            user=os.environ.get('USER'),
            password=os.environ.get('PASSWORD'))

    def close_connection(self):
        self.conn.close()

    def get_connection(self):
        return self.conn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to Postgres DB via python you have used psycopg2 library, according to that, you can try pool connection method which is simple and easy as followed:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import pool

try:
    connect_via = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 20, user="postgres",
                                                         password="pass@#29",
                                                         host="127.0.0.1",
                                                         port="5432",
                                                         database="postgres_db")
    if (connect_via):
        print("Connection pool created successfully")

    ps_connection = connect_via.getconn()

    ps_cursor = ps_connection.cursor()
    ps_cursor.execute("select * from table")
    table = ps_cursor.fetchall()

    for row in table:
        print(row)

    ps_cursor.close()
    connect_via.putconn(ps_connection)

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    if connect_via:
        connect_via.closeall
```

You can also use sqlalchemy to connect the database with pool ideology..

```
def session_scope(self):
    self.db_engine = create_engine(self.db_config, pool_pre_ping=True) # echo=True if needed to see background SQL        
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.db_engine)
    session = Session()
    try:
        # this is where the "work" happens!
        yield session
        # always commit changes!
        session.commit()
    except:
        # if any kind of exception occurs, rollback transaction
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```